# why frontend blocking when accessing the backend which with io operatiion?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I am recently learning the webflux, and I notice that when opearting the IO, the frontend will be blocking when accessing the backend, for example, with this code

```
@GetMapping("/download/test")
    suspend fun downloadFile(response: ServerHttpResponse) {
        val file = File("/home/steiner/Downloads/hello.jpg")
        response.headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM
        response.headers.contentLength = file.length()

        val databuffer = response.bufferFactory().allocateBuffer(bufferSize)
        val outputStream = databuffer.asOutputStream()
        val inputStream = file.inputStream()
        val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)

        coroutineScope {
            var n = inputStream.read(buffer)
            while (n != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n)
                n = inputStream.read(buffer)
            }

            outputStream.flush()
            inputStream.close()
            outputStream.close()
        }
    }
```

when I use postman to access, the result is
[image]

**the frontend is always blocking**
I have tried another code,

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/download")
    suspend fun downloadFile(@RequestBody request: DownloadRequest,
                             response: ServerHttpResponse): Mono<Void> {
        val path = request.path.urljoin(request.filename)
        val file = sambaUtils.file(path)
        val size = sambaUtils.sizeof(path)
        val zeroCopyResponse = response as ZeroCopyHttpOutputMessage
        zeroCopyResponse.headers[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION] = "attachment: filename=${request.filename}"
        zeroCopyResponse.headers[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE] = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
        zeroCopyResponse.headers[HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH] = "$size"
        return zeroCopyResponse.writeWith(file, 0, size).then()

    }
```

this is ok,
and this code is not ok

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.mono

return mono {
   coroutineScope {
      ... io operation
   }
}.then()
```

I am confused now

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Blocking or non-blocking processing is a property of the client and the server separately. From the client perspective it doesn't matter if the server uses blocking or non-blocking processing - they don't even know what's happening in the server. It matters for the server, not for the client. If you don't want to block on the client side, then the client has to implement non-blocking processing.

Comment: eh, I am not sore if I provide correct information. what do I mean is that the frontend blocking at accessing backend forever, and the backend has already finish the job, because I have logged to check, but the frontend still blocked at accessing

Comment: Ahh, ok, I entirely misunderstood your question. I'm not familiar with WebFlux, but are you sure this is how we should send responses? It looks to me you only allocated a buffer and written to it, but that doesn't mean you wrote anything to the client. It's just a buffer, not related to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @broot, I have modify my code to

```kotlin
@GetMapping("/download/test")
    suspend fun downloadFile(response: ServerHttpResponse): Mono<Void> {
        val file = File("/home/steiner/Downloads/hello.jpg")
        response.headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM
        response.headers.contentLength = file.length()

        val databuffer = response.bufferFactory().allocateBuffer(bufferSize)
        val outputStream = databuffer.asOutputStream()
        val inputStream = file.inputStream()
        val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)

        coroutineScope {
            var n = inputStream.read(buffer)
            while (n != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n)
                n = inputStream.read(buffer)
            }

            outputStream.flush()
            inputStream.close()
            outputStream.close()
        }

        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(databuffer))

    }
```

then everything is ok

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: which part should I edit, can you tell me ?